# Cheapest way to enhance soundproofing for an apartment door?

Tags: home, door

I have lived in a studio for two months. The door seems quite thin because I can hear every move outside my room very clearly as if there is no door. How can I reduce the noise from outside my door in a way that induces least cost? I have filled every gap along the door but it does not help significantly. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've already done what you can by blocking gaps around the door.

Next, You can try hanging mover's mats from strong portable over-the-door hooks
Overlap the opening on either side of the door as best you can. Keep the length sufficient to clear the floor as you swing the door open and closed. The mass of the mats and their thick multi-layer construction will block most all but the sounds by contact with the floor from composition shoe heels and similar objects.

You can take them with you as they're not permanent. You can wrap the mover's mat to protect your belongings when you relocate.

If you buy new, when you get to a more private place, they'll make fantastic warm blankets on a cold day.

[image: door hooks] [image: door absorber]

Comment: Thanks. In fact I did not grow up in the US. Could you let me know by the way how much does it cost to have the necessary stuff you were referring to? Thanks. Of a normal quality suffices.

Comment: @GaryMoore Over-the-door hooks are less than $5 Canadian. The thick-heavy "moving blankets" are stock items from moving companies and truck rental agencies. They would probably be ~ $10 (72" x 54"). Online, they are for sale 6 for $60 Canadian, plus delivery. You might need more than one if they are too thin.

Comment: @Alex Thanx for the formatting. I expected you days ago.

Comment: @Stan Haha, you're welcome. It's not like you could've done it like me from the beginning. Just an `m` at the end of the link and a `"Click photo for full size."` after the link. I'm not mad, though. Actually quite pleased to be something like a local celebrity. And sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3):

To Stan’s answer, I would simple add: You could also use an area carpet. Check Craig’sList —people give away these rugs all the time. You can find gently used ones and even new rugs for free.

[image: example]

A decorative carpet could be a more attractive and possibly free, sound-proofing solution. I found this area rug FREE on Craigslist just now.

[image: area rug]

Comment: Thanks! I never tried Craig'slist just heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Line the inside of the door with an insulating material.  Do a google search for: "noise insulation with foam"  to get lots of ideas and prices and sources.
2. Can't resist  :-)  ---- get earplugs or earphones with your favorite music.

Comment: Thanks. I know that you are kidding with point 2, my joking reply is that then someone has to compensate me in monetary form for having to do the additional action

Answer (score 0):

At the hardware store look for look for rubber weather striping designed for exterior doors. Imagine a rubber flap surrounding your door on 4 sides.
The moving blanket idea mentioned previously is great. Motion Picture crews use them all the time to absorb sound. Also called "furniture pads'